# Slowing Down JavaScript Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have a piece of JavaScript that generates every possible combination of a charset for the length provided. Since I'm using it for a length of 12, it's a very long loop that freezes and crashes the browser.

I've tried replacing the `for` loop with a `setInterval()` but it only seemed to break it.

How can I slow down my loop?

Here's the script:

```
var charset = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890',
    charset_length = charset.length;

function recurse(width, pos, base) {
    for (var i = 0; i < charset_length; i++) {
        if (pos < width - 1) {
            recurse(width, pos+1, base + charset[i]);
        }
        console.log(base + charset[i]); // replaced later
    }
}

recurse(12, 0, '');
```

EDIT: Because each output will open a new tab (that will close itself once done), I want to slow it down so a maximum of 5 tabs approx. are open at the same time.

Comment: take a look at webworkers

Comment: I think you're taking the wrong approach here.

Comment: ^ [`4,738,381,338,321,616,896` to be precise.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=36%5E12)

Comment: @dystroy I know, I plan to let this run on another computer and give it as long as it needs.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Could you suggest another?

Comment: You need unmanaged threads

Comment: This might be an obvious question but... why are you doing this? It's unlikely to be a pragmatic solution to any real-world problem.

Comment: @DaveRandom I was asked by a friend to write a script to brute-force a form he made. This is the best thing I could come up with.

Comment: Have you thought about just how long that will take? If each tab takes one _millisecond_ to complete its action (!), you're looking at a mere  `Math.pow(36, 12) / 5 / 1000/ 60 / 60 / 24 / 365 / 1000000` ≈ 30 million years. You may meed another approach.

Comment: @joews Holy... Guess I didn't expect it to take that long... Though it gets significantly shorter if I run more tabs and on more computers... Though still really long...

Comment: You need a better parallelisation solution than web browser tabs ;) GPUs are well suited to this kind of task. I'd guess you're still looking at years, though.